# How can i get tap anywhere on the screen

Tags: java, android, tap

i need a tap function in android. I have full screen activity and want to know if user tap the the screen or not. I looked lots of page and couldn't find the function that i need.

Edit:

I don't know why is unclear to some people. I just need a function that triggers when user tap into screen. How can i explain more clear?

And answer is above, ORIGINAL 's answer. If it is not clear, how ORIGINAL understand this ?

Comment: Please add more description of  your question. it is not clear.

Comment: My question is clear , so Shivam Verma understood and replied my problem.

And i got the solution, and my problem is solved. What is wrong?

Comment: It might be unclear to numerous others. Glad that youe problem got solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set onclickListener to your container layout like this:

```
LinearLayout lay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    lay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onClick(View view, MotionEvent ev)
        {
            ----enter your code---
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Set a click listener to the container layout. (RelativeLayout / LinearLayout ?) This click listener will execute whenever the user taps the screen.